# Failing to rung GWTTestCase tests with ant

Tags: java, gwt, ant, junit, gwttestcase

I simply cannot succeed in running `GWTTestCase` tests. I'm using `GWT 2.6.1`, `JUnit 4.11`, `ant 1.8.2`. I've created sample [repository on github](https://github.com/povilasb/gwttestcase-sample).

Ant target than runs the tests (maybe it's somtehing obvious in here):

```
<target name="test.gwt" depends="javac.test"
    description="Run GWTTestCase tests." >
    <junit haltonfailure="false" includeantruntime="false">
        <sysproperty key="gwt.args" value="-prod -runStyle
            HtmlUnit" />
        <sysproperty key="gwt.persistentunitcachedir"
            value="${gwt.cache.dir}" />

        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${src.dir}" />
            <pathelement location="${test.build.dir}" />
            <path refid="project.class.path" />
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />

        <test name="com.example.client.TestPerson" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

I run tests with `ant test.gwt`, the output I get is:

```
test.gwt:
    [junit] Testsuite: com.example.client.TestPerson
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.848 sec
    [junit]
    [junit] ------------- Standard Output ---------------
    [junit] Loading inherited module 'com.example.Main'
    [junit]    [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
    [junit] java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    [junit]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.createNewSaxParser(ReflectiveParser.java:65)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.access$000(ReflectiveParser.java:46)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:343)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:100)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:176)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.createSyntheticModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:105)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.CompileStrategy.maybeCompileModuleImpl2(CompileStrategy.java:165)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.CompileStrategy.maybeCompileModuleImpl(CompileStrategy.java:112)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.SimpleCompileStrategy.maybeCompileModule(SimpleCompileStrategy.java:36)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1342)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1311)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:705)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:421)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:247)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:518)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeInVM(JUnitTask.java:1420)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:848)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1899)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:800)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
    [junit] ------------- ---------------- ---------------
    [junit] Testcase: testCreate(com.example.client.TestPerson):    Caused an ERROR
    [junit] (see previous log entries)
    [junit] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:336)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:100)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:176)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.createSyntheticModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:105)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.CompileStrategy.maybeCompileModuleImpl2(CompileStrategy.java:165)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.CompileStrategy.maybeCompileModuleImpl(CompileStrategy.java:112)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.SimpleCompileStrategy.maybeCompileModule(SimpleCompileStrategy.java:36)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1342)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1311)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:705)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:421)
    [junit]     at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:247)
    [junit]
    [junit]
    [junit] Test com.example.client.TestPerson FAILED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I've also tried `JUnit 3.8` - did not help. Maybe missing `.*jar` files or not correct versions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to run the `GWTTestCase` tests with `Ant`. The sample project is on [github](https://github.com/povilasb/gwttestcase-sample).

First of all I switched to `junit` task fork mode. Which, as [documentation](http://stefan.samaflost.de/blog/2004/04/15) says,

> In general, forking a new VM is recommended since it isolates your test from Ant's environment (which contains a lot of libraries on the classloader, in particular XML related classes) but it becomes really slow because of the big overhead associated with starting new Java VMs.

Then I managed to get more verbose errors than this `[ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML` when I added `validation-api` package (`ivy.xml`):

```
<dependency org="javax.validation" name="validation-api" rev="1.0.0.GA" />
```

Then it was clear that I was missing `GWT` module for my tests. So I created one (`./test/com/example/MainTests.xml.gwt`):

```
<module rename-to="MainTests" >
    <inherits name="com.example.Main" />
    <source path="client" />
</module>
```

And eventually I had to add tests module path to tests classpath (`build.xml`):

```
<property name="test.src.dir" value="test" />
...
<junit haltonfailure="false" includeantruntime="false"
    fork="true" forkmode="once" >

    <classpath>
        ...
        <pathelement location="${test.src.dir}" />
        ...
    </classpath>
</junit>
```